# Dual monitors setup (embedded + external) doesn't work properly

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, external-monitor

I have very unfortunately bought a Asus Zenbook UX501 laptop. The laptop itself is very good but the Linux support is killing me (all is fine on Windows 10)... One of my big issues is the terrible support of an external (HDMI) monitor.

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Mainline kernel 4.7.x or 4.8.x (needed to somewhat use this laptop)
- NVidia 370.28 or 367.57 or 364.19 or 361.45...

I'm currently using the NVidia driver (Optimus). I recall that when I was using the Intel driver, I didn't have all these problems. But I'm unable to switch to the Intel driver for some months now, since the session is freezing right after a successful login.

My actual problems (with monitors):

1. I cannot invert the locations of the embedded and the external monitors: either I got black screens and I need to unplug the HDMI cable, or some error like *"could not set the configuration for CRTC 63"* (or *"CRT 64"*)
2. sometimes when I plug the external monitor, I get two mirrored monitors without any possibility to get back the two (only one appears in the settings), and I need to reboot for this to go away
3. the NVidia panel never shows 2 monitors, only 1
4. I have also a QHD monitor (2560x1440) and it's never recognized as such, it max out at 1920x1080.

I tried a lot of things, even playing with `xrandr`. The only thing left is ditching Linux altogether which I really don't want to... Any life-saving idea?

Thanks